# Strategy to display this metadata table in a more readable format?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table which is basically a 'metadata table'; it records changes done on the data of another table, with the added caveat of due to a design flaw, we can't do SQL `update` operations and have to delete then re-insert rows when just 1 field on the row is changed, and only each field is recorded per row. For example:

```
Table Customers:

Customer ID | Customer Name | Customer Address |
001 | John F | 213 Privet Drive
002 | Kyle A | 16 Gammon Road

Table Customers-History:

TIMESTAMP         | OPERATION | FIELD NAME  | FIELD VALUE 
1-Dec-2010 19:54:1232| INSERT | CUSTOMER ID   | 001    
1-Dec-2010 19:54:1232| INSERT | CUSTOMER NAME   | Kyle A     
1-Dec-2010 19:54:1500| INSERT | CUSTOMER ADDRESS | 10 Gammon Road  
2-Dec-2010 09:54:9432| DElETE | CUSTOMER ID   | 001     
2-Dec-2010 09:54:9500| DELETE | CUSTOMER NAME  | Kyle A
2-Dec-2010 09:54:9600| DELETE | CUSTOMER ADDRESS | 10 Gammon Road  
2-Dec-2010 09:54:9800| INSERT | CUSTOMER ID   | 001     
2-Dec-2010 09:54:9900| INSERT | CUSTOMER NAME   | Kyle A        
2-Dec-2010 09:54:9600| INSERT | CUSTOMER ADDRESS | 16 Gammon Road   
2-Dec-2010 09:55:9921| DELETE | CUSTOMER NAME | Josh C   
2-Dec-2010 09:55:9925| DELETE | CUSTOMER ADDRESS| 2 Agin Court
```

So from the example above, we see that a customer called Kyle A who lives in 10 Gammon Road has been inserted, then the next day the address was updated to 16 Gammon Road. A while later, customer Josh C is deleted. You will notice that whilst only the `customer address` was edited, as the whole row was removed the `customer name` was also registered as removed and re-inserted. Therefore the name field looks like it was updated, but it actually was not - it was part of the edit on `customer address`.

I want to group the `delete`-`insert` operations up as `update` based on timestamp of operation and field name, show the user that it was actually an `update` operation and maybe only show the fields which were updated as well - in this case, hide results from `customer address`.

My question is, is this even possible on the SQL level (as it returns results the quickest)? If not, what are some strategies I could explore on my SQL query to return the smallest relevant results as possible, which could then be passed on to another component to process?

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you want this readable output to be in your question?

Comment: @toddlermenot see edits, namely, "I want to group the delete-insert operations up as update based on timestamp of operation and field name, show the user that it was actually an update operation and maybe only show the fields which were updated as well - in this case, hide results from customer address."

Comment: Does the sample timestamp data that you have provided represent the time when the `INSERT` or `DELETE` happened? If it is, then you may need to fix them as an `INSERT` or `DELETE` of two fields on a same records could not have happened on different timestamps as the operations are atomic. In your case, the seconds seems to vary for the fields of the same records.

Comment: How close in time do you want to allow the operations to be to group them together?  The larger the window, of course, the greater the possibility of a false positive and the lower the possibility of a false negative.  Is there something that ties the rows of the history table to the primary key of the actual table (which I'm assuming is the `Customer ID`)?  Can you know that the last two deletes affected `Customer ID` 002 while the others affected `Customer ID` 001, for example?

Comment: @toddlermenot the timestamp is made up and does not reflect my real data at all, but you are right in that they are atomic. So generally they should be no more than 1s apart (maybe due to butterflies interfering with solar radiation causing some packet resends or something)

Comment: @JustinCave Not really, this situation I'm in is very ad-hoc (not my fault, before you start scolding me!). There is nothing which ties the rows of the 2 tables and I am not interested in the actualy `Customers` table anyway The control in place is another component which makes this log writes. In reality we should be using a NoSQL solution but, big companies....you know what they're like when it comes to new things....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, an `INSERT` or `DELETE`  is considered to be an `UPDATE` if and only if:

1. `INSERT` as `UPDATE` - The record was `INSERTed` after it was `DELETEed`
2. `DELETE` as `UPDATE` - The record was `DELETEDed` before it was `INSERTed`
3. Under all other circumstances, you would want to present the
   operation as either a standalone `INSERT` or `DELETE` whichever the case

While [3] is straightforward, [1] and [2] pose a problem, as you would need a key to identify if the ***same*** record got inserted after it was deleted so that you can mark that as an update. The ***same*** part here can only be ensured if there is a key which may not change as part of the `INSERT` or `DELETE`. Due to the nature of this problem, I think the key has to be `NATURAL` instead of `SURROGATE`.

The following strategy can be used in such a scenario:

**Step 1:** Query all PK rows with DELETE PRECEDING or INSERT FOLLOWING flag data

**Step 2:** Mark all INSERT or DELETE records as an UPDATE that satisfies our criteria

**Step 3:** Flat out UPDATE records that are currently 2 records [due to Step 2] into a single record

**Step 4:** Use UNION to retrieve the other fields (Customer Address in your example) based on the timestamp of the operation in the resultset of Step 3.

Assuming `Customer Name` is that key for lack of a better column in your example, the following pseudo-SQL code outlines the method to solve the core of the problem [Steps 1&2 only. Steps 3,4 should be simple enough and can be added in the outer queries]

```
SELECT /* 2nd step: Modify Operations to 'Update' if this INSERT id done after a DELETE or DELETE done afteran INSERT */
  CASE
    WHEN 
      OPERATION='INSERT' AND IS_DELETE_PRECEDING_FLAG=1
    THEN 
      'UPDATE'
    WHEN
      OPERATION='DELETE' AND IS_INSERT_FOLLOWING_FLAG=1
    THEN
      'UPDATE'
    ELSE OPERATION
  END AS OPERATION,
  FIELDNAME,
  FIELDVAL,
  OPDATE
  (
    SELECT   /* 1st step: Query all PK records and also the flag information commented below */
      OPERATION,
      FIELDNAME,
      FIELDVAL,
      OPDATE,
      IS_DELETE_PRECEDING_FLAG, --Pseudo Column using Oracle analytics, grouped using the customer name. Is 1 when there is a DELETE preceding, 0 otherwise
      IS_INSERT_FOLLOWING_FLAG  --Pseudo Column using Oracle analytics, grouped using the customer name. Is 1 when there is a INSERT following, 0 otherwise
    FROM
      CUST_TAB_HIST
    WHERE
      FIELDNAME='CUSTOMER NAME' --Assuming this is the primary key
  )  
;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the end we decided to grab everything and do the sorting on another business layer component, because too many things can go wrong and the table could get more complicated in the future. Do you have any tips to cut down in the number of rows returned so we only get relevant ones? Doesn't have to be too complicated

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please clarify what you meant by "relevant ones"? As for cutting down the number of rows, instead of displaying each field for every row, you can do a `PIVOT` after step 4 and display just one whole record with all the required fields.

Comment: e.g. grab only the records which correspond to a field being updated, and remove the ones which are there only because another field got updated.